# Logo não alinha ao menu e centraliza

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Não consigo alinhar minha logo ao menu e centralizar.

---

já tentei criando uma "div", utilizando display: flex;, display: grid;, margin: 0 auto;, margin-left: auto;, margin-right: auto; e   justify-content: center;

---

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap');
:root {
  --white: #ffffff;
  --white-2: rgb(196, 199, 212);
  --black: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  --black-2: #191818bd;
  --blue: rgb(0, 61, 202);
  --blue-2: rgb(148 163 184);
  --blue-3: #4f96c6;
  ;
  --gray: #85888C;
  --yellow: rgb(215, 194, 112);
  --orange: #de7300;
  --orange-2: #a88038;
  --green: #74b087;
  --purple: #9f8198;
  --red: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  --green-white: rgb(27, 172, 47);
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--black);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

@media screen and ( max-width: 740px) {
  article img {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
}

.header {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0px var(--black);
  position: unset;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--black);
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "SF Pro Text", "SF Pro Icons", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}

.menu a {
  display: flex;
  padding: 30px 30px 0 30px;
  color: #cecece;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "SF Pro Text", "SF Pro Icons", "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu a {
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: .8px solid #69696a;
    width: 250px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu,
  a {
    margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
  }
}

.nav {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-out;
}

.hamb {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  padding: 40px 20px 15px 20px;
}

.hamb-line {
  background: var(--black);
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 25px;
}

.hamb-line::before,
.hamb-line::after {
  background: var(--white);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 80%;
}

.hamb-line::before {
  top: 3px;
  width: 80%;
}

.hamb-line::after {
  top: -5px;
}

.side-menu {
  display: none;
}

.side-menu:checked~nav {
  max-height: 28%;
}

.side-menu:checked~.hamb .hamb-line {
  background: transparent;
}

.side-menu:checked~.hamb .hamb-line::before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.side-menu:checked~.hamb .hamb-line::after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    max-height: none;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  .menu li {
    float: left;
  }
  .menu a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: var(--orange);
  }
  .hamb {
    display: none;
  }
}

.alexandre_menu {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
}

.logo {
  width: 2.5em;
  justify-content: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script src="index.js" defer></script>
  <title>Alexandre Ribeiro</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link rel="icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f07fa74e9d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Header -->
  <header class="header">
    <div class="alexandre_menu">
      <svg version="1.1" class="logo" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
                <path fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="10" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M57,283" />
                <g>
                    <path fill="#fff"
                        d="M250.4,0.8C112.7,0.8,1,112.4,1,250.2c0,137.7,111.7,249.4,249.4,249.4c137.7,0,249.4-111.7,249.4-249.4
    C499.8,112.4,388.1,0.8,250.4,0.8z M383.8,326.3c-62,0-101.4-14.1-117.6-46.3c-17.1-34.1-2.3-75.4,13.2-104.1
    c-22.4,3-38.4,9.2-47.8,18.3c-11.2,10.9-13.6,26.7-16.3,45c-3.1,20.8-6.6,44.4-25.3,62.4c-19.8,19.1-51.6,26.9-100.2,24.6l1.8-39.7      
    c35.9,1.6,59.7-2.9,70.8-13.6c8.9-8.6,11.1-22.9,13.5-39.6c6.3-42,14.8-99.4,141.4-99.4h41L333,166c-12.6,16-45.4,68.2-31.2,96.2    
    c9.2,18.3,41.5,25.6,91.2,24.2l1.1,39.8C390.5,326.2,387.1,326.3,383.8,326.3z" />
                </g>
            </svg>
    </div>

    <input class="side-menu" type="checkbox" id="side-menu" />
    <label class="hamb" for="side-menu"><span class="hamb-line"></span></label>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></lia>
          <li><a href="#">Projetos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Answer (score -2):

Tenta adicionar a propriedade "display: inline-flex;" dentro na classe ".alexandre_menu".

**Ficando desse jeito no seu CSS:**
.alexandre_menu {
display: inline-block;
height: 60px;
}

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).